# Error al mostrar una imagen

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Tengo un error al momento que guardo una imagen y la quiero mostrar al index me marca un error en el `return File` diciendo que el valor no puede ser nulo, pero según yo todo está bien, no encuentro porqué me sigue arrojando ese error.

Este es mi *controller*

```
  public ActionResult convertirImagen(int Id)
        {
            var imagenEmpleado = db.Empleados.Where(z => z.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            return File(imagenEmpleado.imagenEmpleado, "image/jpeg");
        }
        // GET: Empleado/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Empleado/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,nombre,aPaterno,aMaterno,numero,rfc,direccion,rol,usuario,contraseña,estatus")] Empleado empleados, HttpPostedFileBase imagenEmpleado)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (imagenEmpleado != null && imagenEmpleado.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                byte[] imageData = null;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(imagenEmpleado.InputStream))
                {
                    imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(imagenEmpleado.ContentLength);
                }
                //setear la imagen a la entidad que se creara
                empleados.imagenEmpleado = imageData;
            }

                db.Empleados.Add(empleados);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(empleados);
        }
```

Y esta es la parte de la vista del index en la que mando a llamar para que cargue la imagen y la otra en donde llamo la vista crear

```
<td>

  <img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Action(" convertirImagen ", "Empleado ", new {item.Id})" />
</td>

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imagenCliente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="file" name="imagenCliente" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El error es al guardar la imagen? o al querer mostrar la imagen guardada?

Comment: Al mostrar la imagen

Comment: Puede ser que al guardar la imagen, la quieras mostrar al instante, no te va a funcionar ya que es una tarea asincrona, debes esperar a que termine de guardarse la imagen

Comment: Si le mandas una petición al server, a ese contorlador de convertirImagen, ¿sí te genera el archivo esperado?